# How to get sender info from request object

Tags: python, html, flask

With three `<a>` all calling the same function:

```
<a id="1" href="call" One </a>
<a id="2" href="call" Two </a>
<a id="3" href="call" Three </a>
```

On a back-end in python using Flask it looks like this:

```
@app.route("/call")
def call():
    print request
```

Now inside of Python `call()` function I get a `request` object. Can I use this `request` to get idea which of three `<a>` were clicked to call the function?

Comment: you can't get this information. You have to add unique argument to every link ie. `href="call?number=1"` or `href="call/1"` and then you can get `number` in Flask

Comment: Please post this as an answer so we could upvote it

Comment: How to you get the `number` in Flask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get information about cliked link from request. You have to add unique argument to every link ie. `href="call?number=1"` or `href="call/1"` and then you can get `number` in Flask.

`href="call?number=1"` needs

```
@app.route("/call")
def call():
    print request.args.get('number', 'no number!')
```

see: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/quickstart/#the-request-object

`href="call/1"` needs

```
@app.route("/call/<int:val>")
def call(val):
    print val
```

see: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/quickstart/#variable-rules